# In Mac, how do I determine in a script (sh/bash/applescript) if currently running via Apple Remote Desktop?

Tags: macos, bash, shell, remote-desktop

I am creating an application installer for Mac. The installer involves getting a code from the user on install. I used an Installer Plugin for the Code Input screen.

I have read (from [this link](http://s.sudre.free.fr/Stuff/Installer/Installer_Plugins/InstallerPlugins-OnceUponATime.html)) and verified that plugins do not work in the command line and Apple Remote Desktop. I can check if the installer is running from the command line using a variable ("$COMMAND_LINE_INSTALL").

My questions is, how can I programmatically check if it is running via Apple Remote Desktop?

Answer (score 0):

If `pstree` is available, you can get a quick ancestry of the current process and see if Apple Remote Desktop is in it, something like `pstree -p $$` in bash. Unfortunately, I installed `pstree` using brew, so this is most likely not going to be available for you, unless you distribute a binary yourself.

The other approach is to walk up the parent yourself. Here is a sample that I tested to be working to check if I am running inside `iTerm` (I used `iTerm` as a sample because I don't know what the `pstree` output would look like when running inside Apple Remote Desktop).

```
pid=$$
running_in_iterm=0
while [ $pid -ne 1 ]; do
    command=$(ps -o command= -p $pid)
    case "$command" in
        *iTerm*)
            running_in_iterm=1
            break;;
    esac
    pid=$(ps -o ppid= -p $pid)
done
if [ $running_in_iterm -eq 1 ]; then
    echo "Running in iTerm"
else
    echo "Not running in iTerm"
fi
```

You can try running this script from both the built-in `Terminal` app as well as `iTerm` and see the difference.